# How to fill such kind of forms using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Link to the site - http://www.prsuuniv.in/login?logout#

After going to site click "Results" tab at the navbar and then select "sem-exam dec-jan 2018-19"

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead.

The website you linked uses Javascript to call the results window. You can't really find it in the HTML Source of the web page.

What Selenium does is, it simulates a browser, enabled with javascript. You can look for elements, wait for them to load, and click on them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some reverse engineering, by exploring the website with the developer tool of a modern browser and reading some js code from the site.

I did this and find that:
The form is loaded from http://www.prsuuniv.in/home/result19 ,
It performs an ajax request once you filled the form and clicked the "Search" button.
The ajax request URL is generated from the field values

```
var urlname="/home/student/result/msw/check19/"+semester+"/"+studentty+"/"+examroll+"/"+coursename+"/resultrack";
```

3 of those 4 field values are just the values of the selected option, while the `examroll` is generated with some random values and the selected option value,

```
var examroll= btoa(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000)+$('#examroll').val()+"@@"+Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000));
```

and all fields are base64 encoded, you need to generate this URL with the same method.

So just build the URL by input values and send a `Request`, if your spider receives the option label(like `Course name=B.Com.`) as input, then you need to request http://www.prsuuniv.in/home/result19 first and convert `B.Com.` to the real value `bcom` by `xpath` or `css` operations, otherwise just send the result request with the built URL.

Also note you need to pass the same headers as from browser, like `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, to get the same result as from browser.